# How to setup Mojolicious with nginx?

Tags: perl, nginx, web, mojolicious

Required to develop a web application using Mojolicious. Therefore required to setup with a web server.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: I am new to nginx and Mojolicious. I have done the following - Install nginx and install Mojolicious. Environment - Ubuntu 14.04. Now how can i configure Mojolicious with nginx

Comment: I imagine that [reading the documentation](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Nginx) would be a good next step.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Mojolicious Nginx](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Nginx) documentation:

One of the most popular setups these days is Hypnotoad behind an Nginx reverse proxy, which even supports WebSockets in newer versions.

```
upstream myapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myapp;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ad:

> Required to develop a web application using Mojolicious. Therefore
>   required to setup with a web server.

isn't true. Just follow the: http://www.mojolicious.org

put into some file, let say: `mojo.pl`

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
get '/' => {text => 'I ♥ Mojolicious!'};
app->start;
```

To run this example with the built-in development web server start it with `morbo`.

```
$ morbo mojo.pl
```

it will answer:

```
Server available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Just [CLICK THIS LINK](http://127.0.0.1:3000) in your browser. You will get

```
I ♥ Mojolicious!
```

And could start the development immediatelly. Setting the `nginx` is enough much-much later - for the deployment.

Comment: We need to handle http request from browser. Will it be possible without server

Comment: @manashb Please take the time to read the mojolicious documentation, it's literally the least you could do (well, besides nothing) since you've chosen to use the tool

Comment: @manashb - just **DO** the above. and **click** the provided  link (yes, click the link in the answer). And you will see, you _don't need the nginx_. :)